# Inequality in probability theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Let $A = \{A_1,A_2,…,A_n\}$ be a set of events , $n\leq \infty $. Let event $B=\{\text{At least $m$ events in $A$ happen}\}$. How can I prove or find a counterexample to the following inequality?
$$P(B)\leq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i)}{m}$$

I've tried to use induction by both $m$ and $n$ but failed to get something good. Search of counterexample didn't give anything too.

I can prove case $m = n$ and case $m>n$ is obvious, but I have no idea for case $m<n$.

Comment: Are the events independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use indicator random variables. Start with ${\bf 1}_B\leq {1\over m}\sum_{j=1}^n {\bf 1}_{A_j}$, and then take expectations on both sides.